# Sync or Update Database from Local to Production Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I have a Windows application installed in PC. It has a 1GB sized database on SQL Server 2000.

I have to create an ASP.NET MVC web application with SQL Server 2012 attached to it. I need to pick some selected data (schema may be different for both DBs) from local DB and put it to remote DB, so that all members of web application can view their personalized data (For example only the sum of last 5 months deposited amount).

1. What architecture approach should I opt for?
2. How will the selected data go to remote DB?
3. What should be the sync approach from local to remote DB for future data.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches one can take here:

- [Setup replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) of your 2000 data to your 2012 server
- Create an ETL process which will load only the data you need from your SQL 2000 database to your 2012 database
- Setup a link between your 2012 server and 2000 server and created stored procedures to retrieve the necessary data

Replication is probably overkill given your scenario. The ETL process is probably the most stable, results in duplicated data. Finally, the stored procedure via link table is probably the easiest and most surgical of the above approaches, but may not be fast enough, depending upon how much data is required at a time.

Does this help?

Comment: Also, note that linking servers is dangerous, as it literally links those servers. If one goes down, it takes the other one with it. ETL or replication are the best approaches.